# Plotting spectrum of a 1D signal

Tags: matlab, fft

I'm trying to do some calculations on a signal. The signal is supposed to be a measured reading from a rfid tag modulated by a block wave around 40 kHz on a carrier wave of 868 MHz. The signal I have is sampled at 250 MHz giving me 1250005 samples that are stored in this [.mat file](http://data.fsfikke.com/antenna_1.mat).

Now I would like to plot the spectrum x[n]. What I'm told to do is do a fft on it of a segment of 1024 samples. Or use Matlabs PSD function. But I'm struggling with this. This is my Matlab code so far:

```
load antenna_1;
x = channel_1;

Fs = 250e6; % Sampling frequency 
t = (0:length(channel_1)-1)*1/Fs; % Time vector 
nfft = 1024; % Length of FFT

X = fft(x,nfft);
X = X(1:nfft/2);
mx = abs(X);
f = (0:nfft/2-1)*Fs/nfft; % Frequency vector

plot(t,x);
xlabel('Time (s)'); ylabel('Amplitude');
figure(2);
plot(f,mx);
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'); ylabel('Power');
```

This last [plot](http://data.fsfikke.com/antenna_2.png) shows me one frequency component around 119 MHZ. Now that's not completely weird because of the aliasing from the 868 MHz signal 868 - 3*250 = 118. But I'm still not quite sure if this is indeed the correct spectrum of my signal? And how would I use the psd function to get the spectrum?

Comment: Your code and the resulting figure look fine to me

Comment: I was expecting to see multiple repetitions of the signal due to aliasing, shouldn't I see those?

Comment: Only one such repetition falls within the observed frequency span (0 -- Fs/2)

Comment: The `psd` function is deprecated, you are supposed to use `pwelch` instead, which is in the signal-analysis toolbox. For correctly estimating the spectrum of a measured signal, this function is much better than doing some FFTs by hand.

Comment: @BasSwinckels thank you, I was trying to figure out how to exactly implement this function. This is what I used:

    load antenna_1;
    x = channel_1;
    Fs = 250e6;
    Nfft = 1024;
    [Pxx,freq] = pwelch(x,hamming(Nfft),[],[],Fs);
    plot(freq,Pxx);

This gives a similar result as before, but still only shows the one component at 120MHz, how would I be able to see more than that?

Comment: @fsfikke Maybe you do not have enough frequency resolution? You should always remember the following rules: `f_res = 1 / t_win`, `t_total = (t_win + 1) / 2` (assuming half-overlapping windows) and `nfft = t_win * f_sample`. You always know 2 out of 3 of `n_avg, t_total and f_res` and then the 3rd one is given. This leads to trade-offs between number of averages (go for `n_avg > 10` or so), frequency resolution and the amount of data you have/should measure.

Comment: @BasSwinckels Thanks, I successfully used the pwelch function now. But I still have a slight problem with it. As posted below.

Answer (score 0):

You've guys been really helpful, thanks for that!

So I used pwelch instead, with following code:

```
load antenna_1;
x = channel_1;

Fs = 250e6;
Nfft = 2^10;
[Pxx,freq] = pwelch(x,hamming(Nfft),[],[],Fs);

figure;
plot(freq,Pxx);
```

Now this works fine and I get roughly the same looking result as before. But now I would like to shift the component that's at ~119MHz to zero. So to get from x[n] to w[n] in this [scheme](http://data.fsfikke.com/scheme.png).
To do that I'm applying following multiplication:

```
n = 0:1:Nfft-1;
w = linspace(0,2*pi,Nfft/2+1);

Pmult = Pxx.*exp(-1j*pi*2);
F = exp(-j*w*119e6).*Pxx';

figure;
plot(freq,abs(Pmult));
```

However I can't seem to get the component to shift at all with this?

Comment: It looks like you want to do some sort of demodulation to shift to peak to 0 Hz by multiplying it with a sine at 120 kHz. You need to do this in the time-domain, before you take the spectrum! But really, answering your own question with another question for more information is not how you are supposed to use StackOverflow. Please read through the help section (link in top-right corner) how to ask good questions. It is better to open a new question for this.